# Equivalent of DB2 function "decimal(numeric expression, precision, scale)" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, type-conversion

Is there an equivalent of the [DB2 function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_decimal.html) `decimal(numeric expression, precision, scale)` in PostgreSQL? Or how would I do this functionality in PostgreSQL?

The `DECIMAL` function returns a decimal representation of a character-string. The value of this second argument specifies the precision of the result. The `scale` value specifies the scale of the result (not sure what that means?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that is a different way of writing a cast:

```
select cast('3.1415926535897932384626433832795' as decimal(12,4)) as pi
```

returns:

```
   pi
--------
 3.1416
```

And

```
select cast('3.1415926535897932384626433832795' as decimal(12,6)) as pi
```

returns:

```
    pi
----------
 3.141593
```

Comment: You can also use the `::` casting operator (in my view, that is a bit more readable).  Also, just for the completeness, `numeric` is a synonym for `decimal` (or the other way around, if you like).